# Deriving the Jacobian with the function a.cos(b-psi)+c results in 0

Tags: python, scipy, mathematical-optimization

I have a dataset which has a cosinus shape. I try to fit this dataset with the function:

```
a.cos(b-psi)+c
```

My goal is to estimate the parameters a,b and c which fit the most with my datas. So I try to use scipy.leastsq to minimize this: `data-a.cos(b-psi)+c`.

(psi is found with the data).

My initials parameters are the `ndarray x (x=np.array([a0,b0,c0]))`, my data are stored in a tuple `args=(psi,data)`, I have my function :

```
def func(x, *args):
psi = args[0].ravel()
data = args[1].ravel()
return np.array(data - (x[0]*np.cos(x[1]-psi) + x[2]))
```

Then I launch scipy.leastsq with the following line :

```
xopt = leastsq(coreg.func,x0,args,full_output=1)
```

(with initial parameters:)

```
Out[30]: array([ 3.8,  1.3,  0. ])
```

but the result is this:

```
(array([ 3.8,  1.3,  0. ]),
None,
{'fjac': array([[ nan,  nan,  nan, ...,  nan,  nan,  nan],
       [ nan,  nan,  nan, ...,  nan,  nan,  nan],
       [ nan,  nan,  nan, ...,  nan,  nan,  nan]]),
  'fvec': array([-3.17913524, -2.19610415, -2.06748506, ...,  1.76355583,
    2.32077375,  2.89394884]),
  'ipvt': array([1, 2, 3], dtype=int32),
  'nfev': 4,
  'qtf': array([ nan,  nan,  nan])},
 'The cosine of the angle between func(x) and any column of the\n  Jacobian is at most     0.000000 in absolute value',
4)
```

I don't know why it couldn't calculate the Jacobian, and I think that's why it gives me back the same parameters as I put initially.

If it can help, here is what the values for each object are:

```
Variable   Type        Data/Info
--------------------------------
args       tuple       n=2
np         module      <module 'numpy' from '/us<...>ages/numpy/__init__.pyc'>
psi        ndarray     1201x1201: 1442401 elems, type `float64`, 11539208 bytes (11 Mb)
data     ndarray     1201x1201: 1442401 elems, type `float64`, 11539208 bytes (11 Mb)
x          ndarray     3: 3 elems, type `float64`, 24 bytes
```

Answer (score 0):

The jacobian matrix of your function is easy to write out analytically. Provide that to the leastsq call.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer !

So I enter the jacobian like this ? (sorry I'm a beginner in python)

```
def jacobi(x,*args):
  psi = args[0].ravel()
  target = args[1].ravel()
  return -x[0]*np.sin(x[1]-psi)
```

But here what's coming back :

```
/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/optimize/minpack.pyc in leastsq(func, 
x0, args, Dfun, full_output, col_deriv, ftol, xtol, gtol, maxfev, 

epsfcn,factor,diag)                                              
367             _check_func('leastsq', 'Dfun', Dfun, x0, args, n,  (n,m))                              
368         else:                                                                                     
--> 369             _check_func('leastsq', 'Dfun', Dfun, x0, args, n, (m,n))                              
370         if (maxfev == 0):                                                                         
371             maxfev = 100*(n + 1)                                                                  

/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/optimize/minpack.pyc in _check_func
(checker, argname, thefunc, x0, args, numinputs,   
output_shape)                                                                          
     28             else:
     29                 msg += "."
---> 30             raise TypeError(msg)
     31     if issubdtype(res.dtype, inexact):
     32         dt = res.dtype

TypeError: leastsq: there is a mismatch between the input and output shape of the  
'Dfun' argument 'jacob'.
```